# How to create a RAM disk - Fedora 17

Tags: linux, ramdisk

How do I create a true RAM disk? I don't want a virtual file system with loop devices, I would like a mountable filesystem that is stored completely in RAM.
I am using Fedora 17, linux 3.6.9-2.fc17.i686
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The real *ramdisk* is deprecated since it uses a fixed allocation, unlike *ramfs* and *tmpfs*.  http://www.linuxfordevices.com/c/a/Linux-For-Devices-Articles/Introducing-initramfs-a-new-model-for-initial-RAM-disks/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) for more details.

Step 1:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/[some-name-or-other]
```

Step 2:

```
mount -t tmpfs -o size=1G tmpfs /mnt/[some-name-or-other]
```

Step 3:

Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

`tmpfs` should do the trick.

```
# mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /path/to/mount/point

# df -h
[...]
tmpfs                            12G     0   12G   0% /home/gert/tmpfs
```

It limits to 50% of your total RAM available by default (configurable - see 'Mount options for tmpfs' in the manpage `mount(8)`).